# Dynamics 365 API Authentication Office Administration password reset

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, office365

If a user in the Office administration portal resets their password, will the client id and secret they've used before still be valid for use in API calls using OAuth? Will the same access token be returned even after password reset?

I would expect so, I believe the username and password is decoupled from the client id and secret auth flow.

Notice how clientid and secret is handled in Azure AD and Username password is handled in the Office admin portal.

**Azure AD App Registration**
[image]

**Office Portal**
[image]

Comment: I believe it will not change your clientid and secret. Did you gave it a try and called API after password changed?

Comment: We have and have confirmed this with the engineering team. Changing password in the Office 365 Admin Center has no effect on Client Id and Secret in Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed this with the product engineering team. Changing a users password in the Office 365 Admin Center has no effect on Client Id and Secret stored in Azure Active Directory.